# fixed element outside of the central content

Tags: html, css, containers, fixed

I am designing a web page with a little toggle menu icon for navigation purposes.

My problem is that whenever the window is resized under the width of the main container (.story, which only has max-width defined), the menu icon overlaps the content.

Instead, I would like the icon to block on the right border of my container.

currently, the code for positionning my nav icon:

```
nav {
    position: fixed;
    top: 100px;
    right: 100px;
}
```

and the container:

```
.story {
    padding-top: 50px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 1000px;
    max-width: 1000px;
    text-align: justify;
}
```

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5etvrLam/) to illustrate my problem.
and here is an example of a [website](http://www.hochburg.net/de/) where they made it work

Thanks for taking a look at it.

Comment: does it need to be the same distance from the edge of the screen (100px) no matter how wide the screen gets?

Comment: Because you have position fixed, it is outside the main flow of the page, so it'll overlap the content block based on the window resize. Setting the nav position to `absolute` will fix that.

Comment: @jmore009 No, this is not necessary.

Comment: @BrianBenett I understand this, but I need the icon to be fixed because it has to remain accessible throughout the whole page (It is a fullpage website)

Here is an example of a website that has this system working: http://www.hochburg.net/de/

Comment: are you sure that the [website](http://www.hochburg.net/de/) you're pointing to has the same system with what you're looking for `(position: fixed)` even on the small screen? have you tested it on the small screen yet for that [website](http://www.hochburg.net/de/), because what happened when I try is that the `style` changed from `position: fixed;` to `position:absolute!important;` using the `CSS Media Query`

Comment: @Kyojimaru You are right, I think using a media query when the icon comes close to the border of the container is the best way to handle this. I cannot think any other way around.

Answer (score 0):

Per my understanding, **position:fixed** will overlap data.

A simple way can be reducing width of **story** div.

#### nav css

> nav { position: fixed; **top: 20px; right: 20px;** }

#### story css

> .story { 
>        padding: 50px 0; 
>        margin: 0 auto; 
>        height: 1000px; 
>        **max-width: 400px;** 
>        text-align: justify;}

Comment: Thank you for your answer, unfortunately, I need my container to be 1080px large one the bigger screens, thus max-width is bound to this value.

Comment: If you want full width container, then what you can try is to have a NAV bar on top that can hold stuff like Brand name, menu and search bar and fix that NAV on top. 

OR you can take create a div with fixed height and then put you  story div inside that div. So you will have scroll of div and of page.